# WPF Event Trigger Change Other UI element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, event-triggers

I defined `ListBox` in my XAML which uses `ItemTemplate`.
Inside the `ItemTemplate` I placed Image.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
 <ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <WrapPanel x:Name="itmTempPanel" IsItemsHost="True" ItemWidth="60" ItemHeight="60" Width="{Binding ElementName=lstFilesDropped, Path=Width}"/>
 </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
...
<Image>
 <Image.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
   <BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="71" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="itmTempPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="71"      Duration="0:0:0.3" />
    </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
  </EventTrigger>
 </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

When the mouse enter the image I want to begin storyboard on that image height **and** on the `WrapPanel` which I defined inside the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

When the mouse enter to this image I got the following exception:
"'itmTempPanel' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'."

How can I change other element property from element that begin the storyboard.

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this. The first is using `{x:Reference}` a feature in .NET 4.0 for WPF. You should follow this approach if your application targets .NET 4.0. The idea is setting the `Storyboard.Target` to the object you want to animate (in this case is the `WrapPanel`). Although we can use `Binding` for `Storyboard.Target` but we cannot use `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` to set the binding source because `Storyboard` (or Timeline) is not a FrameworkElement (or FrameworkContentElement). The only way to specify the source is setting the `Source` property. However we can normally set this to a `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` or directly (using element syntax). It's fortunate that the `{x:Reference}` was introduced in .NET 4.0 and this can help you reference any named object inside XAML (the way it works is not like `ElementName`). Here is the code for the first approach:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding Source={x:Reference itmTempPanel}}" 
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                 To="71" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
```

The second approach is based on `DataTrigger`. However this trigger is not for `Image`, it's exactly for the `WrapPanel`. But now the `ElementName` can be used to bind the Trigger source to the `Image`. So this approach is usable when `{x:Reference}` is not supported.

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="itmTempPanel" IsItemsHost="True" ItemWidth="60" ItemHeight="60" 
           Width="{Binding ElementName=lstFilesDropped, Path=Width}">
  <WrapPanel.Style>
     <Style TargetType="WrapPanel">
        <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,ElementName=image}" 
                        Value="True">
               <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                   <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                                      To="71"  Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                   </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
               </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
           </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </WrapPanel.Style>
</WrapPanel>

<Image Name="image">
  <Image.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="71"
                            Duration="0:0:0.3" />     
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

Note that you have to give the `Image` a name (such as `image`). The `<DoubleAnimation>` for the WrapPanel is removed. Instead of using `EventTrigger`, we used `DataTrigger` listening to `IsMouseOver` property. You can also specify the `DataTrigger.ExitActions` to start animating when `IsMouseOver` is false (equal to `MouseLeave`).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much ! I so appreciate this, this very helped me to, finally, understand how to manage animation by xaml only. Again, thank you !!

Comment: Small correction. `x:Reference` was introduced in .Net 4.0 and not in .Net 4.5.

Comment: And is there official MSFT documentation on this ? where they describe how to animate parent from child event ? how one learns about this without SO ?